# Transform CRS and strip decimal places

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm using the following expression in the QGIS attribute form default value expression box to transform the CRS EPSG:3857, EPSG:4326:

```
  y(transform($geometry,'EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326))
```

This works perfectly, but I'm trying, (unsuccessfully thus far), to work out how to edit this expression so as to strip the float returned to 6 decimal places.

I've also used ...

```
left("Lat-Y-coord",9)
```

... in the attribute table field calculator to trim this field, but when I sync this data backwards and forwards to a Cloud repository, it reverts back permanently to the full length float. So I'm looking to input a single expression in the attribute form default value expression box to achieve both transform and strip results.

Comment: Did you try to format the destination field's precision to 6?

Comment: Thx for this for your answer. I think that is only available for 'Create a new field' option and not for 'Update existing field' which is what I was using.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid rounding the result, you can simply define the field length accordingly. So if you define Output field precision to 6, all numbers will be automatically rounded to 6 digits.

Use `Menu Processing > Toolbox > Refactor Fields` to create a copy of your layer with changed field precision.

*Defining Precision when creating a new field:*
[image]

Answer (score 3):

One can try one of the following expressions:

```
format_number(y(transform($geometry,'EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326')),6)
```

It uses the [`format_number(number, [places=0], [language])`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#format-number) function:

> Returns a number formatted with the locale separator for thousands. By
> default the current QGIS user locale is used. Also truncates the
> decimal places to the number of supplied places.
>
> places - integer representing the number of decimal places to truncate the string to.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much indeed, this is what I was after and it worked flawlessly. I'm relatively new to Python/PyQgis still, so I wasn't composing the expression just quit right and fumbling about to get it. Thx again!

Comment: Incidentally, the reverting back to long float upon syncing with Cloud was actually caused by something else I had misconfigured in the attribute form so I was able to get the result I wanted with my original default value expression combined with the field calculator expression, but this single:  
       format_number(y(transform($geometry,'EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326')),6) expression is, I think, a much better aproach.