# Numeric issue with labels (QGIS adding decimals)

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am encountering numeric issues, possible related to this problem: [QGIS labels rounding error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370573/qgis-labels-rounding-error/449139?noredirect=1#comment733573_449139)

I have a field value of 0.55 (type double NULL) that I want to display in a label as a percentage. The expression for the label is `concat(FIELD*100,'%')`. The label for this object is shown as `55.00000000000001%`.

It only happens for certain values, but always for the same ones: `14%` becomes `14.00000000000002` and `28%` becomes `28.00000000000004`. For other layers, the same thing happens with the `ROUND` function used in the label expression, for the values `57%`, `58%` and `110%`. The problem recurs whenever those same values come up, in different layers.

Does anyone have this problem, or better yet, found a solution? For now, I get around by adding rounding, or rounding at a different place in the formula.

QGIS version is 3.22.9.

Comment: So rounding works as you want? So what is the problem? It seems like to be a rounding error (if percent number are calculated based on some values and do not result exactly in what you expect). You vould try converting the numbers to integers, using `to_int()` function

Comment: Rounding errors occur, but the same numeric issue occurs when I just want to convert a (already rounded) number to a percentage, e.g. 0.55 to 55%. I have work-arounds, but to_int() would probably work too. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Changing field length might be another option, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/430360/88814

Answer (score 3):

You can format the number when you change it to a string using the `format_number` function:

> ### function format_number
>
> Returns a number formatted with the locale separator for thousands. By default the current QGIS user locale is
> used. Also truncates the decimal places to the number of supplied
> places.
>
> #### Syntax
>
> format_number(number[,places=0][,language])
>
> [ ] marks optional components
>
> #### Arguments
>
> number number to be formatted places integer representing the number
> of decimal places to truncate the string to. language language
> (lowercase, two- or three-letter, ISO 639 language code) used to
> format the number into a string. By default the current QGIS user
> locale is used.
>
> ### Examples
>
> format_number(10000000.332,2) → '10,000,000.33' if e.g. the current locale is an English variant
> format_number(10000000.332,2,'fr') → '10 000 000,33'